# split by comma ignoring specific commas C#

Tags: c#, split

I have a string which looks like this :

> NULL VALUE,25,000-30,000,31,000-32,000,33,000-50,000

How can I split it so I obtain :

> NULL VALUE or 25,000-30,000 or 31,000-32,000 or 33,000-50,000

I tried to split using a regex but without luck, it returns

```
NULL VALUE
25
000-30
000
31
000-32
000
33
000-50
000
```

I've tried like this `Regex.Split(items[1], ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")` but it doesn't return what I need.

note from editor: extracted from comments

If the value is a thousand value, it must not split at comma, if not it should split at comma i.e
`NULL VALUE,25,000-30,000` should be `NULL VALUE | 25,000 - 30,000`

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] with sample inputs and expected outputs based on those inputs.

Comment: What are the possible values?  Could you have ranges with larger numbers like `12,225,000-230,599,300,000` for example?

Comment: Also, "tried regex"...let's see what you tried?

Comment: you may have issues in that you are using a thousand separator. Is that specifically required?

Comment: Regex.Split(items[1], ",(?=(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*$)")

Comment: This is going to be tough to phrase.  For example, does `31,000-32,000` resolve to `31 or 000-32 or 000`, or does it mean `31,000-32,000`?

Comment: it means 31,000-32,000

Comment: I just need to split by comma, but ignoring the comma in the intervals like "31,000-32,000"

Comment: by what you're explaining you should consider changing the seperator char @Frey_ja, if at all possible. If not, you'd have to check for 3 following digits.

Comment: `([A-Z ]{1,}|\d{1,},\d{3}-\d{1,},\d{3}|\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}|\d{1,},\d{3}-\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}-\d{1,},\d{3})` this regex should do the trick.

Comment: Unless this is more restricted (for example "input will never have numbers with two decimal separators, like 123,456,789") this is not parsable in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a nightmare trying to parse like this and you probably won't ever get it 100% error free. If at all possible, try to get the values with a proper seperation character.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string x = "NULL VALUE,25,000-30,000,31,000-32,000,33,000-50,000";
        string regexstring = @"([A-Z]{1,} [A-Z]{1,}|\d{1,},\d{3}-\d{1,},\d{3}|\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}|\d{1,},\d{3}-\d{1,3}|\d{1,3}-\d{1,},\d{3})";
        var erg = Regex.Split(x, regexstring);
        foreach (var item in erg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

it produces:

```
NULL VALUE
,
25,000-30,000
,
31,000-32,000
,
33,000-50,000
```

This solution works at least with your test values. You'd have to remove the empty strings and commas but well, it parses the given values properly.

Comment: Yes, it does what I need, thanks a lot, and for editing my comment as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

In fact, what you want is detect ranges, from A to B. A can be any number, from 0 to X and B can be any number from 0 to X.

Given this, you will face the following cases:

```
1-10
1-10,000
1,000-10,000
1,000,000-2,000,000
NULL VALUE
```

Once you've found a pattern for thoses matches, you'll be able to extract any ranges.

You can use this regex: `([A-Z ]+|(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)-(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*))` that means:

```
(
    [A-Z ]+#NULL VALUE
    |#OR
    (?:
       \d{1,3}#A trailling number
              (?:,\d{3})*#Followed or not by a thousand separator and 3 digits
    )
    -#The range separator
    (?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)#Same thing here
)
```

Within C# code, it gives:

```
var input = "NULL VALUE,25,000-30,000,31,000-32,000,33,000-50,000";

var regex = new Regex(@"(
                        [A-Z ]+#NULL VALUE
                        |#OR
                        (?:
                           \d{1,3}#A trailling number
                                  (?:,\d{3})*#Followed or not by a thousand separator and 3 digits
                        )
                        -#The range separator
                        (?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)#Same thing here
                    )", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);

var matches = regex.Matches(input);

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    // Do what you want here, I choose to output it.
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); 
}
```

Which outputs:

> NULL VALUE
>
> 25,000-30,000
>
> 31,000-32,000
>
> 33,000-50,000